# Query the table with array in the where clause in PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, arrays, oracle, plsql

I have the list of employee_id's as an array. How do I query the table with array in the where clause in PL/SQL?

empIdArray = [1,2,3]

```
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID IN (empIdArray);
```

Comment: post a [mcve] please

Comment: SQL or PL/SQL doesn't have an array datatype

Answer (score 1):

That would be something like this (see line #8):

```
SQL> declare
  2    empidarray sys.odcinumberlist := sys.odcinumberlist(7369,7499,7521);
  3    l_names    sys.odcivarchar2list;
  4  begin
  5    select ename
  6    bulk collect into l_names
  7    from emp
  8    where empno in (select * from table(empidarray));      --> this
  9
 10    for i in l_names.first .. l_names.last loop
 11      dbms_output.put_line(l_names(i));
 12    end loop;
 13  end;
 14  /
SMITH
ALLEN
WARD

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```